# An Experimental Question

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Take a small peice of paper about 1cm by 1cm in size. Take a pen and start drawing circles on it continuously. you will notice that the paper rotates in an opposite fashion to that of the direction of the motion of your pen.

Now, considering the pen has a ball on its tip and we are providing it with force which gives the centre of mass its acceleration. so, for rolling Frictional force must be acting in the backward direction i.e opposite tothe direction of motion of the pen.

By newton`s third law of motion , the peice of paper would be getting a forward frictional force as a reaction. As a result, it should move in the same direction as the pen WHICH obviously does not match with the observations.

I think I`m somewhere wrong. Can anyone help with this?

Thank You

Comment: The outcome of my experiment differs from yours.

Comment: nope, i have tried it many times

Comment: try on a different surface maybe and spin with different sppeds, then maybe..

Comment: any development, mate?

Comment: I did not mean to say that you were wrong, only that our experiments differed.  Upon trying it with a few different surfaces, the counter-rotation seems to occur only on relatively "soft" surfaces like paper.  I also notice that the small piece of paper rocks back and forth, so it looks not unlike how you would rotate a piece of furniture that you couldn't lift.

Comment: I'd have to think about it, but I suspect the answer is related to how the small square lifts away from the underlying paper except at the point of contact with the pen.  Perhaps someone else will have more insight in the meantime.

Comment: yeah it works on soft surfaces. and btw I can`t  think of any reason why but do please share if you get any new idea.

Comment: At a minimum the dependence on the underlying surface means that you have to include the interactions between the paper and the underlying surface in your model. Worse, it probably means there is enough deformation going on that using the simple $f = \mu N$ model of friction is insufficient.